# Can I use enums at key position of Json

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, express, enums

I am using typescript Nodejs (MEAN stack)

Trying to use `enum` at property/schema of json

An example enum would be like

```
Enum KeyEnums {
  A: "featureA",
  B: "featureB",
  C: "featureC"
}
```

Expected JSON

```
{
  featureA: "This is feature A",
  featureB: "This is feature C",
  featureC: "This is feature C"
}
```

The way I am trying to achieve

```
{
  KeyEnums.A: "This is feature A",
  KeyEnums.B: "This is feature C",
  KeyEnums.C: "This is feature C"
}
```

But, getting an error saying

```
"Property or signature expected"
```

..anyway to achieve use of enums at JSON property place ?

Comment: Is it what you want? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBRcEDOUDeBYAUFKAglALxQBEAZsAIYAuYATsAWQDS74BCJ5VdjwTmw5QAwj0o16TUWVwBfXLgDGAexCpaUaqWx4oAbThIUqAHQEAugC5yAFQAWAS3QuofacELD9RhMkhzTht7Z1d0DwExH3w-E0CzURCyRzc3SKZohSUcNQ0tACtUdR4AKQBlAHkAOTNNBicQAHMnCngACmoAShV1YoAbYDN+1Sb2ovUuoA

Comment: @Anatoly Exactly.. thanks a ton !!!

Comment: @Anatoly If you add it to comments, i will ACCEPT, and complete this question thread !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap enum keys by `[` and `]` like this:

```js
enum KeyEnums {
  A = "featureA",
  B = "featureB",
  C = "featureC"
}

const a= {
  [KeyEnums.A]: "This is feature A",
  [KeyEnums.B]: "This is feature C",
  [KeyEnums.C]: "This is feature C"
}

const json = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(json)
```